# How do I make my code procedurally generate 2D platforms?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development, instantiation, procedural-generation

I'm making a 2D endless jumping game and I'd like the game to of course be endless. I'm trying to make the platforms generate procedurally and have the code to do so but nothing's generating. The code is basic, if the player is lower than a generation point, which is connected to the player but always above by the y distance of 20, then generate platforms with a y distance of 10 in between up to the position of the generation point. I'm just kinda stuck and don't know how to fix this.

```
public GameObject platform;
public Transform generationPoint;
public float distance = 10;
public GameObject player;

void update()
{
    if(player.transform.position.y < generationPoint.position.y)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y * distance);
        Instantiate(platform, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that your Update function is not spelled correctly. It should be spelled as "Update" with an uppercase starting letter. If that does not fix it, then use Debug.Log to figure out what part of the code is running and what isn't. Also make sure that you are setting and using the correct variables. Also, are you sure you want to do "transform.position.y * distance" and not "transform.position.y + distance?"

Comment: Man I feel silly, it was the Update function being misspelled. Thank you so much!

Comment: @retnuH Don't worry! It happens to the best of us.